# Cannot run react native project on Mac M1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

English is not my native language so it might be hard for you to understand, sorry in advanced.

I'm using an Macbook Air M1 and I'm trying to create a React Native to run using Xcode following this guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#installing-dependencies

I already follow the guide and it all going well until I get into the " npx react-native run-ios " part because it always throw back into me with errors:

[Error when running npx react-native run-ios][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdoQR.jpg

I tried to run using the workspace file inside the ios folder but it also throw me with this error:
[Using both Native or Rosseta mode][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huZEZ.jpg

Also, when trying to run the workspace file it will not run metro, metro will only auto start if I run the project file (I also did manually run metro with project file but no luck)

I have search here and google with so many attemps to fix: running terminal and xcode in Rosseta mode, excluded arm64, comment #flipper but nothing works.

No, to be more correct, somehow something worked 2 days ago and I was manage to build and run my app through Rosseta mode but after 2 days,it no longer works.

I'm really not sure what to do or how to fix this, if anyone got a guide how to make this work with M1 mac can you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

have you installed react-native-cli before you did this 'npx react-native run-ios'?

Comment: Would be good to use comment section to clarify than posting a question in the answer section